# MacBook Air 2013 not updating software

Tags: macos, high-sierra, software-update, software

New to this site.

2013 MacBook Air refurbished from IBM in 2017.
Factory reset accidentally to original software: Mountain Lion.

I could update 6 items. The last iTunes update comes with an error code.

I downloaded OS software on my iPhone, from my iPad, and also from a 2013 Windows 8.1. Placed on USB and SD card bootable drive but MacBook cannot download this new software.

I need to get my MacBook up and running and I need help. Downloaded many different versions of macOS from Mountain Lion to Big Sur.

Comment: Reformatted the SD & USB to have a partition. 
Now I can’t add more msg software or delete anything from them.

Comment: Welcome.  Sorry, to say, but this is a bit all over the map.  Let’s start with Internet Recovery to install the latest operating system compatible with this Mac. Reboot and hold `Cmd-Opt-R`.  Wipe the drive and install the OS. Post an [edit] with the results.

Comment: Hey Allan. Thanks. Apple walked me through Cmd-Opt-R. Result: Mac was able to download 95% of the software update, except for the ITunes update. Came with a 202 error code.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense.  You should be downloading a full installer of the latest compatible version not an update.  At 95%, it wouldn’t work at all.  What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: @Allan Mountain Lion (in the question) ;)

Comment: From Mountain Lion you will need to get Sierra next. That will then allow you to see the App Store properly, to proceed further. If the Mac is currently operational, merely out of date, you need to get the Sierra installer .dmg file onto the Mac & then open it & run it. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos for links, alternative download solutions [you may need an http solution rather than https] & in case you cannot get the dmg onto the Mac & running properly, further instructions on building your own Boot USB.